# Remove line break after single-statement if with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to get clang-format to leave if-statements with one statement on the same line.

Example input:

```
if(is_finished) break;
if(foo) {
    // do something
}
```

clang-format output:

```
if(is_finished)
    break;
if(foo) {
    // do something
}
```

Wanted output:

```
if(is_finished) break;
if(foo) {
    // do something
}
```

None of the space related options seem to match this style.

current config:

```
---
Language: Cpp 
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 8
UseTab: ForIndentation
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
BraceWrapping:
  AfterControlStatement: false
```

Comment: you can play with https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ to define your configuration interactively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant config option is `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine`.

The choices are:

- `Never`
- `WithoutElse`
- `Always`

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 2):

```
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine
```

And

```
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine
```

The first one does what you want, `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` will also allow code such as

```
if (expression) { Something(); }
```